# Request authorization on PrincipalPermission fail

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've got a service some methods of which have PrincipalPermissionAttribute. I want to request authentication if check for principal has failed.
For example:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrator")]
public string GetData()
```

If calling user is Administrator, service should return data.
If calling user is not Administrator, service should request authentication and if it has failed, service should return 401 response. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to do this with a helper class:

```
internal static class UserPermissions
{
    public static bool CheckRole(Role role)
    {
        try {
            var p = new PrincipalPermission(null, role.ToString());
            p.Demand();
        }
        catch (SecurityException) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void AssertRole(Role role)
    {
        if (!CheckRole(role)) {
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}

public enum Role
{
    Administrator,
    Customer
}
```

With such usage:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
        public List<Order> GetOrders()
        {
            UserPermissions.AssertRole(Role.Customer);
            // Code to get orders.
        }
}
```

So, I gave up the idea of ping-ponging authentication requests and just return 401 error instead.